# Redis Structure for Realtime Analytics

Tags: php, model, schema, redis, analytics

I'm using Redis as the datastore for a real-time analytics app.

Suppose that a client pings the server every 20 seconds to indicate that it's alive.

What's the most efficient way to model this in Redis?

Each client has a clientid and each visitor has a uid.

I've thought of approaching this like:

clientid_realtime is the key and it contains a hash which are the uid:timestamps of each ping, but this would require that I get all the hashes and sort them.

Also, each hash key would grow wildly over time and become very large..

Comment: Yeah, not sure how to apply them here though. Are you suggesting using timestamps as the value to sort with?

Comment: yes, store timestamps as score and user data as value

Comment: Make it an answer @GaneshKumar so I can vote it up :)

Answer (score 0):

If sorting is a top requirement you should use sorted sets. to increment the scores you only need to use the command zincrby with a value of 1